# Controlling the amount of pixels when scrolling down

Tags: jquery

I wanna alert a message after I scroll pass 300 pixels and then another message after I scroll pass 600 pixels.

But at the moment it is only alert when I scroll pass 300 pixels.

Here my js:

```
var hasBeenTrigged = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 300 && !hasBeenTrigged) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
    alert("You've scrolled 300 pixels.");
    hasBeenTrigged = true;
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 600 && !hasBeenTrigged) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
    alert("You've scrolled 600 pixels.");
    hasBeenTrigged = true;
   }
});
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Your issue is the `hasBeenTriggered` flag. It's set after the first 300 pixels. You need to either remove it, or have separate ones for 300/600px scroll points

Comment: you are setting `hasBeenTrigged` to true in 1st condition, which is blocking the 2nd `if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 600 && !hasBeenTrigged)` as `hasBeenTrigged` is already `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 2 variables `hasBeenTriggedAt300` and `hasBeenTriggedAt600`
So, something like this:

```
 var hasBeenTrigged300 = false;
 var hasBeenTrigged600 = false;

   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 300 && !hasBeenTrigged300 ) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
        alert("You've scrolled 300 pixels.");
        hasBeenTrigged300  = true;
     }
     if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 600 && !hasBeenTrigged600) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
        alert("You've scrolled 600 pixels.");
        hasBeenTrigged600 = true;
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var hasBeenTriggedFirst = false;
   var hasBeenTriggedSeccond = false;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 300 && !hasBeenTriggedFirst) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTriggedFirst is set to false.
        alert("You've scrolled 300 pixels.");
        hasBeenTriggedFirst = true;
     }
     if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 600 && !hasBeenTriggedSeccond) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTriggedSeccond is set to false.
        alert("You've scrolled 600 pixels.");
        hasBeenTriggedSeccond = true;
      }
   });
```